# C++Builder App Uses Wrong Icon Whenever a .wav File Is Embedded

Tags: icons, c++builder, wav, embedded-resource

I've migrated (not copied and pasted) an app to C++Builder 11.2. It uses an embedded `.wav` file that's referenced from an `.rc` resource file.

Here's the problem: The app's icon becomes a default Windows image (not a default C++Buider image) when the `.rc` file is part of the project. But the icon is normal when the `.rc` file is removed from the project. This happens with both a 32-bit and 64-bit compile.

So, I can have either the correct icon or the sound, but not both. Is there a fix or workaround for this problem?

Comment: Embedding a resource (especially an audio resource) should have no effect on the app icon, unless it happens to overwrite the app's main icon resource.  What does your `.rc` file actually look like? Did you verify with an external resource viewer that your compiled `.exe`'s resources are what you expect? And, what did "*migrated (not copied and pasted)*" involve, exactly?

Comment: Remy, Thanks for responding. My response was declared too long, so I'm responding with separate comments. First, I've never heard of an external resource viewer. Does Embarcadero offer such an animal? If not, can you recommend one?

Comment: Second, the .rc file contains one line: 100 WAVE "My Sound File.wav". The sound file is invoked with this line: PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(100), HInstance, SND_RESOURCE);

Comment: Finally, as briefly as I can described it, this is my procedure for migrating a project: Copy the old project folder and all of its contents to a new folder; delete all of the folders in the new folder; delete all files except .cpp, .dfm, .h and any files (like .rc) that I created; create a new VCL app; remove the Unit1.cpp file from the project; add my original main .cpp file to the project; add all of the other .cpp files to the project; perform a Save Project As...; double-click the main .cpp file to open the code listing; click the Design tab to see the main form; compile and run.

Comment: All of that info belonged in your original question, not posted in comments. That being said, there are plenty of resource viewer tools readily available, such as [Anders Melander's Resource Editor](http://melander.dk/reseditor/), [XN Resource Editor](https://stefansundin.github.io/xn_resource_editor/), just to name some.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I'll check them out. I felt that brevity would be more likely to attract readers/responders to my post. The .wav file is nearly 1MB. Could its size be a problem?

Comment: Maybe it's some manner of static vs dynamic linking issue. You could perhaps try to link the .rc file into a .res file and then add the .res file to the project? If I remember correctly it will then get linked together with the executable.

Comment: @Lundin resources are not linked dynamically. And the compiler already handles the steps you describe when an `.rc` file is added to the project

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay. Perhaps I'm mixing this up with ye olde "Borland command line tools".

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've used Resource Editor as you recommended. When the .rc file is **NOT** part of the project, these are the listed resources in the .res file: RCDATA, Icon, VersionInfo, Manifest. These are the listed resources in the .exe file: String table, RCDATA, Cursor, Icon, VersionInfo, Manifest. When the .rc file **IS** part of the project, this is the only listed resource in the .res file: WAVE. These are the listed resources in the .exe file: String table, RCDATA, Cursor, WAVE. Why would the resources change so dramatically depending on the presence of the .rc file?

Comment: @BobPenoyer rather than posting *relevant* details like that in comments, you should [edit] your question instead to add the details to it. In any case, if what you say is true then the IDE has a serious flaw that Embarcadero will need to fix. Adding a user-defined `.rc` to a project should not eliminate any standard resources that the IDE defines (VersionInfo, Manifest, etc) especially when the `.rc` does not overwrite them. That is definitely a bug worth [reporting to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've used this site very little and am still low on the learning curve. I will attempt to make a bug report as you have suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: FWIW: I filed a bug report with Embarcadero in November. They reported today that they have duplicated the problem.

Comment: I posted a bug report in November (RSP-39966). It's now June and there has been no feedback since January, so I'm going to assume there will never be a resolution to this problem. The last posting on the bug report was from an Embarcadero product manager: "We'll look into this report, but we really don't recommend adding a large binary file to a resource file, even less to the main resource file of the project. Possibly, using a secondary resource file might work." The icon problem that I've described here had not been a problem, but it became one. This suggests that there must be a solution.